# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:12.0.1

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, google-places-api, google-places

when I implement google places dependency and sync the Gradle file then it shows an error

Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:12.0.1

> App-level build. Gradle file

```
apply plugin : 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hatimtekri.googlemap"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

> dependency

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'

please please solve this error

Comment: Show your project level Gradle file

Comment: Please try the following: (1) migrate to AndroidX (2) ensure that google() is listed in your project-level build.gradle, and (3) remove implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'. Let us know if this resolves the issue (it does on my end).

Comment: @evan it does not work with me

Comment: @Ankur_009 I see, in that case can you please post all relevant code and files so that we can reproduce this on our end? (your activity, manifest...) Also verify that your API key is valid (is it properly restricted? is your billing account in good standing? is Places API enabled?) And do please double check that you've fully migrated to the new Places SDK following this guide https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: I need to remove the "if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
            details.useVersion '11.4.0'
        }" from the app:build and update the com.google.gms:google-services to 4.3.3 @evan

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you resolved your issue! ^^